# Linear Predictive Coding to get back original audio file from LPC coefficients Python

Tags: python, compression, signal-processing

I am attempting to use Linear Predictive Coding to compress an audio file by encoding the file with LPC to get the residual signal and encoding that signal with Rice coding. I need to be able to retrieve the original audio file back from the compressed signal. I found this LPC code to encode and decode audio files but the  decoded audio file has strange, messed up audio. How do I edit the LPC code to decode the coefficients so I would get the original audio back? Currently, the decoded audio is a noisy and unintelligible version of the original audio file.

Here is the code that encodes the audio file to get the LPC coefficients. The result is the predicted coefficients and signal power.

```
def make_matrix_X(x, p):
    n = len(x)

    xz = np.concatenate([x[::-1], np.zeros(p)])
    
    X = np.zeros((n - 1, p))
    for i in range(n - 1):
        offset = n - 1 - i 
        X[i, :] = xz[offset : offset + p]
    
    return X

"""
Encodes the input signal into lpc coefficients

x - single channel input signal
p - lpc order
nw - window length
"""
def lpc_encode(x, p, w):  
    n = len(x)
    nw = len(w)
    
    # overlapping factor
    R = 0.5
    step = floor(nw * (1 - R))
    nb = floor((n - nw) / step) + 1
    
    # list of overlapping blocks
    B = np.zeros((nb, nw))
    
    for i in range(nb):
        offset = i * step
        B[i, :] = w * x[offset : nw + offset]
    
    # the coefficients
    A = np.zeros((p, nb))
    
    # the signal power
    G = np.zeros((1, nb))

    for i in range(nb):
        x = B[i, :]
        
        b = x[1:].T
        
        X = make_matrix_X(x, p)

        a = np.linalg.lstsq(X, b)[0]

        e = b.T - np.dot(X, a)
        g = np.var(e)
   
        A[:, i] = a
        G[:, i] = g
    
    return [A, G]
```

And here is the code to decode the coefficients to get the audio file but the audio is all messed up after decoding. The inputs are the predicted coefficients, signal power and the number of poles.

```
"""
Decodes the LPC coefficients

* A - the LPC filter coefficients
* G - the signal power(G) or the signal power with fundamental frequency(GF) 
       or the full source signal(E) of each windowed segment.
* w - the window function
* lowcut - the cutoff frequency in normalized frequencies for a lowcut
          filter.
"""
def lpc_decode(A, G, w, lowcut = 0):
    [ne, n] = G.shape
    nw = len(w)
    [p, _] = A.shape
    
    # list of overlapping blocks
    B = np.zeros((n, nw))

    for i in range(n):
        src = np.sqrt(G[:, i])*randn(nw, 1) # noise
    
        b = np.concatenate([np.array([-1]), A[:, i]])
    
        x_hat = lfilter([1], b.T, src.T).T 
        
        B[i,:] = np.squeeze(x_hat)

    # recover signal from blocks
    [count, nw] = B.shape
    R = 0.5
    step = floor(nw * (1 - R))
    n = (count-1) * step + nw
    
    # the rendered signal
    x = np.zeros((n, ))

    for i in range(count):
        offset = i * step
        x[offset : nw + offset] += B[i, :]
        
    return x
```

The code to run the functions:

```
[sample_rate, amplitudes] = scipy.io.wavfile.read('Sound1.wav')
amplitudes = np.array(amplitudes)
w = hann(floor(0.03*sample_rate), False)
        
# Encode
[A, G] = lpc_encode(amplitudes, 6, w)
        
# Decode
xhat = lpc_decode(A, G, w)
scipy.io.wavfile.write("example.wav", sample_rate, xhat)
```

Comment: What is your source of the code details? Textbook?  White paper?

Comment: @zipzit https://www.kuniga.me/blog/2021/05/13/lpc-in-python.html